# Formatting date and time in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want yesterday's date as "MMdd", like "0418" today's date is "0419".

I tried this:

```
$d = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) | select -Property Month,Day
$e = $d.Day

$d = $d.Month

$total = "$d" + "$e"

Write-Host $total
```

But the output was "418".

As you can see, this is a three-letter string, but I want a four-letter one. Because I want to search files they have that format and created a day before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date object has a method `ToString`, which allows you to specify the format:

```
$d = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1);
$d.ToString("MMdd");
```

I am calling this on April the 20th, and the output is

> 0419

See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) for a description of the available date format strings.